# Is it possible to change the group of a file if I am not part of that group?

Tags: command-line, permissions, chown

Is it possible to use chgrp or chown to change a file's group to one that I as the owner am not a part of? I own the file, but I am not part of the group that I want to change it to, so can it be done without using sudo?

Comment: No you need to be either in that group or you should be admin.

Comment: Though technically correct what @mordoc posted I see 1 loophole in your question that allows you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you need to be a member of that group to give that group permission as per this link:

https://serverfault.com/questions/462174/using-chown-to-change-the-group-owner-of-a-directory-is-not-permitted-why

sudo is your only option...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. As long as you have physical access to a machine you do not need `sudo`.

- Reboot.
- Enter grub rescue mode. To do so, when GRUB is presenting the menu list (you might need to press `ESC` to show the menu while booting), follow those instructions:

  - Use the arrows to select the boot entry you want to modify.
  - Press `e` to edit the entry
  - Use the arrows to go to kernel line
  - Press `e` to edit this entry
  - At the end of the line add the word single
  - Press `ESC` to go back to the parent menu
  - Press `b` to boot this kernel

You will get a root prompt and can use `chmod`, `chown` and `chgrp` without `sudo` or being part of that file's group.